# Get specific frequency from audio input using pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, frequency-analysis

Iam trying to analyze my audio out (I made my audio out become a audio in using a virtual cable and get specific frequencies with their amplitudes.

I managed to find some code that could find the frequency with the highest amplitude. I have tried to understand fft and everything around it but i cant seem to figure out how to filter on specific frequencies.
This is what i have so far:

```py
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

# Audio variables
CHUNK = 4096
RATE = 44100
power = 12

# Opens audio stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=RATE,input=True,frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

while True:
    # Reads the data
    data = np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16)

    # Calculates the peak of the frequency
    peak = np.average(np.abs(data))*2

    # Shows the bars for amplitude
    bars = "#"*int(50*peak/2**power)

    # Calculates the frequency from with the peak ws
    data = data * np.hanning(len(data)) 
    fft = abs(np.fft.fft(data).real)
    fft = fft[:int(len(fft)/2)]
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(CHUNK,1.0/RATE)
    freq = freq[:int(len(freq)/2)]
    freqPeak = freq[np.where(fft==np.max(fft))[0][0]]+1

    # Shows the peak frequency and the bars for the amplitude
    print("peak frequency: %d Hz"%freqPeak + " "+bars)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Can one of you guys help me and explain how to filter on frequencies?
(If it isn't clear what i want/am trying just ask and ill try to explain better)